# VBA - Excel Organizing/Duplicating Data

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking for a way to duplicate and rearrange some data that I have using a macro or a function that exists. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advanced!

J

The data is unique ID numbers listed in Column A like below.

[image: Unique ID Numbers - Starting Point]

I am trying to have each number duplicated 4 times in a row like the below image...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub myMacro()

    ' where data is
    Dim rowData As Integer
        rowData = 2

    ' where data is duplicated 4 times
    Dim rowNew As Integer
        rowNew = 1

    ' loop through all entries of column A
    Do While Range("A" & rowData).Value <> ""

        Do While rowNew Mod 4 <> 0

            ' copy
            Range("B" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData).Value
            rowNew = rowNew + 1

        Loop

        ' last copy
        Range("B" & rowNew).Value = Range("A" & rowData).Value
        rowNew = rowNew + 1

        ' next row
        rowData = rowData + 1

    Loop

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

With your data in column **A** in **B1** enter:

```
=INDIRECT("A" & ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0))
```

and copy down

Then copy column **B** and Paste/Special/Values back onto column **A**

Comment: `=INDEX(A:A,ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0))` avoids the volatility ;)